# Matching Attribute value to key in XSL

Tags: xslt

I have a key defined in my XSL file, where you pass in a string equal to the value of node "d" to return parent node "c":

```
<xsl:key name="column" match="/a/b/c" use="d"/>
```

Each node "c" has a unique @position attribute.

I need to use the key function for this to match the @position attribute of another node, "x", which @position value will match the value of the @position attribute in the "c" node, like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/a/x[@position='##']/y/z"/>
```

I want to replace ## in the attribute matching statement with the equivalent of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('column','foo')/@position"/>
```

I have tried to use the expression shorthand in curly braces, like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/a/x[@position={key('column','foo')/@position}]/y/z"/>
```

but that did not work. I could define a variable that is equal to the key value:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="key('column','foo')/@position"/>
```

and use that variable in the attribute equality statement:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/a/x[@position=$var1]/y/z"/>
```

but that creates an unnecessary extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use curly braces in `select` attribute expressions:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/a/x[@position=key('column','foo')/@position]/y/z"/>
```

Obviously that asks for a key `match="a/x" use="@position"` and simply

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('k2', key('column','foo')/@position)/y/z"/>
```